# check for the last item in a javascript array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops

I have this array which I iterate through by using $.each(...).
But I need to do something to the very last item in the array.
so I need to know in the loop that if it's the last item, then do something.
thanks a lot ;)

Comment: would you post your array.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you can use `.pop()` method:

```
console.log(myArray.pop()); // logs the last item
```

[Array.prototype.pop()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) The pop() method removes the last element from an array and returns that element.

---

Simple test scenario:

```
var myArray = [{"a":"aa"},{"b":"bb"},{"c":"cc"}];
var last    = myArray.pop();
console.log(last); // logs {"c":"cc"}
```

so now you can store it in a var and use it.

Answer (score 10):

send index as parameter to the function

```
$.each(arr, function(index){
    if(index == (arr.length - 1)){
        // your code
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Just add a second parameter to the function. This works both in jQuery and in native array.forEach method.

```
$.each(arr, function(item, i){
  if (i === arr.length-1) doSomething(item);
});

arr.forEach(function(item, i){
  if (i === arr.length-1) doSomething(item);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access both the index and current Array value within the $.each callback.

Warning: using .pop() as suggested in other answers will directly delete the last item from your array and return the value. Not good if you need the array again later.

```
// an Array of values
var myarray = ['a','b','c','d'];

$.each(myarray, function(i,e){
  // i = current index of Array (zero based), e = value of Array at current index

  if ( i == myarray.length-1 ) {
    // do something with element on last item in Array
    console.log(e);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Or use the reverse() method on the array and do your thing on the first element.